# Stuck on an integral

Tags: integration

The context is not relevant here. The point is that I have to calculate this integral in terms of $\theta$:
$$\int_0^\infty x^2e^\frac{-x^2}{2\theta^2}dx.$$
I have to use the following hint:
$$\int_0^\infty y^2e^\frac{-y^2}{2}dy = \int_0^\infty e^\frac{-y^2}{2}dy = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} .$$
I don't know what to do with the $\theta^2$, can someone please help.

Comment: Try setting $y=\frac{x}{\theta}$.

Comment: Use an appropriate substitution to remove $\theta$ from the exponential.

Comment: @carmichael561 Would $\theta^3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ be correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Put $\frac{1}{2\theta^2}=\lambda>0$ and then use differentiation under integral sign

$$
I(\lambda)=\int_{0}^\infty \mathrm e^{-\lambda x^2}\mathrm d x=\frac 12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}
$$
then $$
I'(\lambda)=\int_{0}^\infty (-x^2)\mathrm e^{-\lambda x^2}\mathrm d x=-\int_{0}^\infty x^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda x^2}\mathrm d x=....
$$

Answer (score 0):

Probabilistic approach:

Recall that if $X\sim N(0, \theta^2)$, then 
$$
Var(X)= EX^2 = \theta^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi \theta^2}}e^{-x^2/(2\theta^2)}dx,
$$
also note that 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi \theta^2}}e^{-x^2/(2\theta^2)}
$$
is an even function that is integrated over symmetric region, thus $\int_{\mathbb{R}} fd = 2\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}fd$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2/2\theta^2}dx=\theta^3\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2/2}dx.$$